# Como adicionar IdURI no Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, indy-10, delphi-2010

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que eu preciso idURI que é do indy e o Delphi 2010 não tem.
Eu preciso disso para pegar um código e concatenar com a data atual e enviar via url com esse código no final.
Alguém pode me ajudar a instalar ou me passar outro caminho para trabalhar com EncodeBase64.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você que fazer. O código e a data vem da aplicação Delphi ? Você precisa concatenar esses dados e acessar um link com esses dados?

Comment: @VictorZanella. Sabe como eu instalar o componente?

Comment: Não tenho o Delphi 2010 aqui, mas se você der uses em IdURI, e criar um objeto do tipo TIdURI, não vai funcionar ?